# shadowPath is not working with UIButton

Tags: uibutton, swift, calayer, shadow

I am creating a button like this:

```
let authorizationButton = UIButton()
    let authorizationButtonHeight = 50.0
    let authorizationButtonX = 10.0
    let authorizationButtonWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - authorizationButtonX * 2
    let authorizationButtonY = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - 10.0 - authorizationButtonHeight

    authorizationButton.frame = CGRectMake(authorizationButtonX, authorizationButtonY, authorizationButtonWidth, authorizationButtonHeight)
```

After that I am trying to add a shadow with my own shadowPath like this:

```
        authorizationButton.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect:CGRectMake(authorizationButton.frame.origin.x, authorizationButton.frame.origin.y,
        authorizationButton.frame.size.width, authorizationButton.frame.size.height)).CGPath

    authorizationButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    authorizationButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    authorizationButton.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
    authorizationButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)
```

My real shadow path is much more complicated.

Shadow is not displayed at all.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to set clipToBounds to false? also, maybe you have to instantiate the bezier path using origin (0,0)

Comment: @mxb, doh... you r right, origin should be (0,0). Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the bezier path: the origin should be 0,0.

Change your code as follow:

```
authorizationButton.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect:
    CGRectMake(0, 
               0, 
               authorizationButton.frame.size.width,
               authorizationButton.frame.size.height)).CGPath
```

Comment: More often than not, the rect you've created here would be the same as `authorizationButton.bounds`.

Comment: Thank you so much! `CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: frame.size)` and `bounds` both work perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but for anyone who still stumbles upon this problem, move your shadow code to an extension and call it in viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewWillLayoutSubviews, because shadowPath require bounds or frame of the view to be calculated.

example:
`override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() myButton.applyShadows() }`